# Extjs render image inside iframe

Tags: extjs, iframe

I have div inside iframe which Im trying to use for rendering image. This code can read div element, but I cant render image to it:

```
var element = window.frames['pf'].document.body;            
    var canv1 = Ext.get(element).select('canv1');
    var changingImage = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src: '/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/EnterpriseOrg-MainChannel-Site/ProductStore/ru_RU/kzch.jpg',
        renderTo: Ext.get(element).select('canv1'),
        style: {
            cursor: "crosshair"
        }
    });
<iframe ..>
<div id='canv1'></div> 
</iframe>
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why do you use an iframe? It looks like your code is executed before the dom is ready. Also, what do you get if you `console.log(canv1)` right after you set it with var?

Comment: el: constructordom: undefinedel: constructordom: undefinedel: constructor__proto__: Element.Fly.AbstractElement.Fly.Ext.Class.constructor__proto__: Element.Fly.AbstractElement.Fly.Ext.Class.constructorattach: function (dom) {config: objectClassconfigMap: Objectconstructor: function (dom) {initConfigList: Array[0]initConfigMap: ObjectisFly: trueself: function constructor() {superclass: Object__proto__: Objectelements: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]__proto__: Ext.define.constructor

Comment: very long message - cannot be post here. I can see el->dom: undefined - can it be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ext.getDom('canv1') instead

Comment: Error gone but nothing is rendered somehow.

Comment: @lorenz is probably on the right track here. You should wrap your JS code in an Ext.onReady handler

Comment: No even inside on ready it doesnt work. The only suggested way is to load new extjs library inside new frame but how can I pass a previosly loaded  store to it?